# How to use Kryo FieldSerializer with Lombok @Data annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, kryo

I am trying to use Kryo Serializer as default serailzer in SpringBoot 2.1. However, Kryo serializer do nothing for Box class with lombok @Data annotation. It always return `{}`. Is there a way I can use the `@Data` annotation with Kyro FieldSerializer?

```
@DefaultSerializer(FieldSerializer.class)
@Data
public class Box implements Serializable {
    private String content;

    public Box(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it do something **without** `@Data`?

Comment: @pirho Yes, it works well if I get rid of the `@Data` annotation and put the getter and setter. I assume that `@Data` annotation works first

Comment: Can you add your Spring configuration related to Kryo or if doing manually the code to serialize / deserialize?

Comment: @pirho I am a newbie for spring. The `@DefaultSerializer(FieldSerializer.class)` annotation is the only thing for serialization using kryo.